# get_plugins() is not give plugin list after performed delete_plugins()

Tags: php, wordpress

Upon performing delete_plugins() action, get_plugins() is give deleted plugin list.

For example:

```
delete_plugins(array('akismet/akismet.php'));
get_plugins();
```

Is I am doing something wrong? Any one give some insight about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added one more line to clear the cache its working now

```
delete_plugins( array( 'akismet/akismet.php' ) );
wp_clean_plugins_cache( false );
get_plugins();
```

Answer (score -1):

This question has been [answered here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54742/how-to-do-i-get-a-list-of-active-plugins-on-my-wordpress-blog-programmatically). Here is the chosen solution-

> The activated plugins are stored in the options table of a WordPress
>   Blog under the key active_plugins
>
> so you can use get_option('active_plugins'); of each blog and compare
>   the arrays.

Comment: If deleted plugin was inactive plugin status what will we do ?